# How to open multiple browser tab that has the same url using python +selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browser, tabs

I am using python and selenium to do a load test. What I need to do is search a system and display its event content. Currently I have :

```
test_url = base_url + args.system + event_page_url_addon
```

The issue is that if I have 5 threads of this event going on, they have the same URL because they are all looking for the same system, and I have 5 different tabs all with the same URL. My question how do refer to each tab/thread? ( tab1, tab2....) If I manipulate the URL by adding an index number at the end, then the site became unsearchable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: get the window handles...  Selenium has a method for getting the current window handle, getting all window handles and switching the driver between those handles.  This will only be a single thread... you can use one thread per driver per browser... but Selenium is not good for load testing.  There are other tools for that.

Comment: Hi pcalkins, thanks very much for the help. What is a good tool to do load tests of a web page, if selenium is not a good tool for this ppurpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why are you using Selenium for load testing, You may wanna have a look at [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

Having said that, for this particular task, you can switch between tabs. You can go to any tab from any tab in Selenium.

I would assume that you have click somewhere on the first tab and then a new tab must have been opened, right ?

If that is the case, you can use the below sample code :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("Your URL here")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
first_tab_handle = driver.current_window_handle  #Storing the current or first tab windows handle
driver.find_element_by_id('some id').click() # the moment this click take place, you would see a new tab with some other or with same content (Assuming this click triggers an event)
two_tabs_handles = driver.window_handles   # Note that, two_tabs_handles will have previous tab (first tab) as well as second tab handles. 
driver.switch_to.window(two_tabs_handles[1])  #  Note that, window_handles returns a list in python, so [0] denotes the first tab whereas [1] denotes the first tab. 

#perfrom some operation here on tab 2 (e.g click somewhere to open tab3 using selenium)

three_tabs_handles = driver.window_handles 
driver.switch_to.window(two_tabs_handles[2])

and so on...
```

PS :- Read out the comments for better understanding.